# Remind me: How do we convert coordinates to space with different basis and origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matlab

I'm stuck with the very beginning of my homework. I might've even misunderstood the task. I'll try to translate the assignment in case I fail to explain what I need later:

> #### Task description:
>
> Every student has his own task, described in external file. On the image for your task, you'll see two coordinate systems: $O$, $\beta$ and $O^\prime$, $\beta^\prime$ where bases are:
>
> - $\beta\,=\,(\vec{b_1},\vec{b_2})$
> - $\beta'\,=\,(\vec{b_1}',\vec{b_2}')$
>
> #### Tasks
>
> 1. Write coordinates of basis vectors $\beta$ in basis $\beta'$.
> 2. Write coordinates of basis vectors $\beta$ in basis $\beta$.
> 3. Write formula to convert coordinates of system $O^\prime$, $\beta^\prime$ to system $O$, $\beta$.
> 4. Implement Matlab function that converts coordinates of system $O^\prime$, $\beta^\prime$ to coordinate system $O$, $\beta$.

Therefore this whole task is based upon converting between systems with different origin and base. This is one of basic things we were taught in Linear algebra year ago. Year is a long time and I have forgotten almost everything.

I could look up that for 2D systems, [change for vector $v$ to basis $\beta^\prime$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Two_dimensions) can be done as:

$$v^\prime = {\beta^\prime}^{-1} v$$

But what about the beginning point $O'$? For illustration, here's my assigned image:

[image: image description]

And I'll be given vector $v'$ in the $O^\prime$, $\beta^\prime$ coordinates. My task will be to convert it into $O$, $\beta$ coordinates. I'm sure this must be simple matrix equation.

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Basis_and_coordinates may be worth a read.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP's friend helped to figure it out.

Comment: @KurtG. Wait what? That doesn't sound like a valid close reason :D

Comment: This is an eight year old question. Your friend helped out eight years ago. If there is still anything not answered feel free to elaborate. If not: the question describes an isolated problem of little general interest.

Comment: @KurtG. The problem is clearly defined. The fact that a question is not about a widely popular problem is not a reason to vtc. VTC prevents further answers, it does not do anything else and exist to prevent answers to questions that cannot be reasonable answered. This question has both the math answer and the code example.

Comment: "The goal of Math SE is to create a repository of high-quality questions about mathematics with corresponding high-quality, authoritative answers." 
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34763/949989 . Your question can be closed as it does not call for further answers. And BTW: don't worry. So far we only have one out of five necessary close votes. Even if we get five you can edit the question and vote to have it reopened.

Comment: BTW: you know what prompted me to vote for close? Now I remember: the bot pushed that question into the active queue saying "This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed." Apparently it took you eight and a half years to accept the answer and avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it's simple. You have to (left) multiply the $\beta'$-coordinates of $v'$  by the change of basis matrix (change from $\beta$  to $\beta'$), the column vectors of which are the $\beta$-coordinates of the vectors in $\beta'$.

To combine this with the change of origin, observe that for a point $M$, we can write $$\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OO'}+\overrightarrow{O'M}.$$

The coordinates of $M$ in the $(O,\beta)$ system are the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{OM}=\vec v$ in basis $\beta$. Its coordinates  in the $(O',\beta')$ system are the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{O'M}$ in basis $\beta'$.

Now the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{O'M}=\vec{v'}$ in basis $\beta$ are $P\vec{v'}$ and observe the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{OO'}$ are expressed in basis $\beta$. Thus:
$$\vec v=\overrightarrow{OO'}+P\vec{v'}.$$

Comment: But what about the origin/beginning ($O$, $O'$)? Also is this what you mean: $v^\prime = {\beta^\prime}^{-1} v$. I'm not native English speaker, if you describe equation verbally I can lose it in translation.

Comment: Oh! It's for the affine structure. In addition, add the coordinates of vector $-\overrightarrow{OO'}$.

Comment: But in which order do these operations happen? I tried to multiply first or subtract first but our retarded homework evaluation system always says it's wrong.

Comment: You have to multiply first, then add or substract, depending on which direction you want to convert. I'll add some details to my answer in a moment.

Comment: Well my friend already helped to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The actual matlab command:

```
% Convert vectors in Xi from base B2 and origin O2 to B1 and O1
function Xo = mybasetrans(O1, O2, B1, B2, Xi) 
   % We'll need ones matrix which then expands into long matrix 
   % depending on how many vectors are in Xi
   n = size(Xi);
   n = n(2);
   % This is the shift of origin points, using the canonic coordinates
   zeropoint = (O2-O1)*ones(1, n);
   % This is the matrix multiplication
   % to convert vector to base use inv(BASE)*vector
   % so backwards, to convert it to canonic, use BASE*vector
   % In this case, we convert from B2 to B1
   Xo = B1\(B2*(Xi) + zeropoint);
end
```

The equations for one vector are:

$$v = {\beta}^{-1}({\beta^\prime} v^\prime + O^\prime - O)$$

The multiplication must be from the left!